# C++: Extend an enum definition?

Tags: c++, enums

The Java code by Oracle tends to use constant integer identifiers where the equivalent would be an enum in C++. The nice thing about using the CIIs that you can easily add more in the base class or a derived class and not break the code (*too* badly...). My question is: Is there a way to achieve this using an enum in C++ or would I have to stick to constants?

Comment: You can also add values to a C++ enum without breaking existing code.

Comment: Except if they had not values associated with and you add to the beginning.

Comment: @Grozz : That's only a problem is in v1 if didn't care about the values (accepted the defaults), and in v2, you did (assigning the new identifiers particular numbers).   Which, in general, is a breaking change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in Java because it's bytecodes are interpreted (or, more likely recently "Just-in-Time" compiled) : You have separate pieces and they are put together at run-time.

C++ is fully compiled to native code.  Any change will require a ful compile.  If a full recompile is acceptable, then adding a new item to a enum is possible, and even less likely to break code than adding CIIs.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that you are unable to change the original enum declaration and you absolutely need to do this it's possible using a static cast.

```
enum ENUM_TYPE {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
};

static const ENUM_TYPE VALUE4 = static_cast<ENUM_TYPE>(VALUE3 + 1);
```

Comment: This has a drawback in C++11: using a scoped enum (`enum class ...`), a `switch` statement with `VALUE_4` as one of its `case`s will trigger the `-Wswitch` warning (if you're using that warning).